# error method called before start element java sax processor

Tags: java, sax

I am parsing an xml document using java sax parser and validating it against a schema. When validating for empty elements, the parser works fine if the the element is of the following format

```
<submitmonth></submitmonth>
```

The error i receive is good ( Says that submit month be null and should be such and such ). The order in which the code executes is

1. start element
2. validation error
3. end element

when using short hand xml

```
<submitmonth/>
```

, the method call order seems to change. I noticed the call order to be below

1. validation error
2. start element
3. end element

Not sure why this is happening. I would expect the short hand to be handled the same way as regular xml

Help please

Answer (score 1):

There is no guarantee in SAX about when errors are reported versus when start and end element are reported. Your program should probably be written to tolerate that variation.

If you think a parser should be more regular about that behavior, take it up with that parser's authors or try another SAX parser.

There really isn't anything we can do here beyond offering those two suggestions.

Comment: I am using the out of the box jdk api and am also a little concerned about the comment. Is it possible that an end tag will be called befor the start, although i have not noticed this behavior?

Comment: No. End tags will not occur before start. Errors, however, are essentially a side channel.

Comment: Sorry but one more clarification, the errors related to a particular tag will be completely done before the next tag starts correct? in other words the start,end,error call backs will be done before the start of the next tag?

Comment: Start and end will be sequenced as they are in the document.

I'm not sure there is any promise regarding exactly when errors are reported. It's fairly common to give up parsing the document after the first error has been found, since it isn't at all clear how to recover from the error and the correction could affect whether anything later in the stream is or is not well formed or valid.

Comment: I am maintaining the state of the Element and associating the errors to the 'current' element before persisting. If the errors are reported out of order then it could be an issue. For example the the error associated with the second occurence of a tag is reported before the first?

Comment: I understand what you're trying to do. I'm honestly not sure whether SAX's error reporting permits doing it that way. I haven't yet found a clear statement about when errors are reported relative to other events, and undefined behavior is simply undefined. I'll take another look, and I'd be delighted if someone else can find evidence to prove me wrong, but...